# Как в listview посчитать сумму всех чисел строки с 3 столбца и до столбца Успевающих

Tags: c#

Как в listview посчитать сумму всех чисел строки с 3 столбца и до столбца Успевающих и отправить получившийся число в столбец "Всего"

Код добавления из базы данных в listview

```
      DbDataReader dataReader = null;
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `" + bds + "`", sqlConnection);
        try
        {
                //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            dataReader = await cmd1.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            //Read the data and store them in the listview
            if (dataReader.FieldCount > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == 0)
                        {
                            listView1.Columns.Add(dataReader.GetName(0), 0, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            listView1.Columns.Add(dataReader.GetName(i).ToString().Replace("_", " "), 80, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                        }
                    }

                    ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
                    //
                    while (await dataReader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        lv = listView1.Items.Add(dataReader[dataReader.GetName(0)].ToString().Replace('_', ' '));
                        for (int h = 1; h < dataReader.FieldCount; h++)
                        {

                            lv.SubItems.Add(dataReader[dataReader.GetName(h)].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 1; i < listView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                    listView1.Columns[i].Width = -2;

        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: получить значения каждой колонки и сложить?

Comment: @tym32167 получить значение строки и отправить эту сумму в колонку "Всего "

Comment: наверное лучше сложить числа в момент, когда вы запрашиваете данные из БД?

Comment: приложите код доставания из бд данных...очевидно вы их группируете (но это не факт) и в этот момент можно их сложить

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц я добавил код

Comment: согласен я думаю ван тут уместнее поправить sql запрос, и сделать поле "всего" вычисляемым например:
`select no, fio, ... , vacation, illness, duty, truancy,
vacation + illness + duty + truancy as  total from bds`

Comment: @Ackbar проблема в том что имена столбцов буду меняться, не изменными буду оставаться только первые 2 столбца и последние 6

Comment: @АндрейReyz что то не понятное у вас твориться...если столбцы будут меняться - это значит что их будет менять пользователь...я все правильно понял?

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц  Да

Comment: @АндрейReyz так меняйте столбцы/базы сколько хотите в виде параметров, только это наиболее простой способ, потому что в гриде (таблице у клиента) если это делать так же надо будет описывать колонки и хранить их где то, либо перенесите запрос на бд в виде хранимой процедуры с параметрами

Comment: @АндрейReyz что за программа дает пользователю работать с БД на прямую ? Ну сделайте тогда один столбец "общий" и храниет в нем данные в стринге по типу `[ключ => значение], [ключ => значение], ...` и потом парсите и слажуйте. Почему такая странная задача? Какая конечная цель данных полей?? возможно стоит пересмотреть структуры БД?

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц учебная программа. Дело в другом. я могу получить все  названия столбцов, вывести их куда то, затем удалить из этой переменной названия столбцов которые не нужны

Comment: @АндрейReyz там где вы получаете имена полей...создайте `2 int-переменные`. В первую запишите первое совпадение по названию от которого идти индекса, во вторую - индекс окончания. И дальше складывайте только ряды с индексам, которые будут между переменными